# MongoDB group by non standard $week custom start day of week

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm building a dynamic software that gives the ability to set custom start day of week depending on the business needs.
Therefore we have `start_day_of_week` a number represents the day.

Now on grouping by mongodb the `$week` property will consider the week starts on Monday.

But I want to make it start based on the value of `start_day_of_week` it might be Saturday, Sunday any day of the week.

I can't even think about an idea to do this, can you enlighten me please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/week/index.html) is quite clear:

> Returns the week of the year for a date as a number between 0 and 53.
>
> Weeks begin on Sundays, and week 1 begins with the first Sunday of the
> year. Days preceding the first Sunday of the year are in week 0. This
> behavior is the same as the “%U” operator to the strftime standard
> library function.

You may check [$isoWeek](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/isoWeek/)

If you like to group by other days, then you can work with offset, e.g.

```
{ $isoWeek: { date: { $add: [ "$date", 3*24*60*60000 ] } } }
```

to group on weeks starting by Thursday.